# Extract img src using alt

Tags: java, jsoup

Here's the image element

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/abc.jpg" 
 alt="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" />
```

Now, I want to use multiple keywords to figure out the correct img element. And this is what 
found in jsoup's [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

```
doc.select("img[alt*=fox]")
```

**I want to use multiple keywords** .
I want to check for all the keywords that I have in the alt tag.

For example: fox,dog,lazy,quick

What is the correct way to do it.

I hope that makes up for a clear question.

Comment: How do you want the multiple keywords to act? If you have "fox" and "dog" should it match fox AND dog or fox OR dog (or something else)?

Comment: I want both the approaches (AND and OR). Since I've few keywords that are mandatory and other optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) that @Sage links, you can also pass in multiple selectors separated by commas. So if you want all `img` elements that has an `alt` attribute that contains either `fox` or `toy` you could say

```
doc.select("img[alt*=fox],img[alt*=toy]")
```

This will return an array of `Element` objects that match your criteria

Comment: +1. I like the approach. But what If i have more than 10-15 keywords.

Comment: At some point you're going to have to write down all of those keywords. You might put them somewhere that is easy to maintain and build your selector query dynamically using string builder or something, but there's really no getting around having to write down all your keywords.

Comment: Yes, Agree with you. selector query can be build dynamically using keywords. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the `[attr~=regex]` pattern: elements with an attribute named "attr", and value matching the regular expression.

[Check out the documentation page for details.](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Thanks, Can you suggest the regex for multiple keywords? (AND and OR).